# Console in new window

Tags: python, shell, console

I want the commands that run a python file with console
are in an independent window

my code:

```
def update(self):
        self.prombt("sh /usr/script/update.sh")
        self.close(None)

    def prombt(self, com):
        self.session.open(Console,_("sTaRt ShElL cOm: %s") % (com), ["%s" % com])
```

it's possible?

Tank's

Comment: Not entirely sure what you're asking. Perhaps you're looking for the [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/subprocess.html) module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can realize this using the subprocess module.

```
import subprocess

subprocess.call(["gnome-terminal", "-x", "sh", "/usr/script/update.sh"])
```

In this example I used "gnome-terminal" as my terminal emulator. On your system you may not have this emulator and you should replace it with the one you use (e.g. Konsole for KDE).
You must then also find the appropriate parameter (in this case "-x") to execute the command, when opening the emulator.

Answer (score 0):

To accomplish this, you can use either `subprocess` or `os.system()`.

Whichever one you use, the bash command to do so would be:

```
gnome-terminal -e sh /usr/script/update.sh
```

for `subprocess`:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(["gnome-terminal", "-x", "sh", "/usr/script/update.sh"])
```

for 'os.system()'

```
import os
os.system("gnome-terminal -e "sh /usr/script/update.sh"")
```

It is recommended you use `subprocess.call()` for anything more complex than simple commands as `os.system()` is outdated.

Comment: i use, enigma2 , on box, this plugin for E2

Comment: no work.. 

code
def update(self):
  os.system("gnome-terminal -e sh /usr/script/update.sh")

Comment: This.. not work.. 

def update(self):
  subprocess.call(["/bin/sh", "sh", "/script/update.sh"])
  self.close(None)

Comment: @paolozanone im not sure why. however, that is not the `subprocess` command I recommended.